# Using addPosLimit and osMaxPos throws "error in PosLimit[, "MaxPos"] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Tags: r, quantstrat

Even if I copy paste example from blog.fosstrading.com/2011/08/tactical-asset-allocation-using.html I get this error:

```
 error in PosLimit[, "MaxPos"] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

**Output from sessionInfo():**

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] dplyr_0.4.3                   quantstrat_0.9.1687           foreach_1.4.2                
 [4] blotter_0.9.1695              PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3662 FinancialInstrument_1.2.0    
 [7] quantmod_0.4-5                TTR_0.23-0                    xts_0.9-7                    
[10] zoo_1.7-12                   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1      lattice_0.20-33  codetools_0.2-14 assertthat_0.1   grid_3.2.2      
 [6] R6_2.1.1         DBI_0.3.1        magrittr_1.5     iterators_1.0.7  tools_3.2.2     
[11] parallel_3.2.2
```

Comment: I just ran the code in the blog post and it worked. I'm using the latest revisions of quantstrat and blotter. Please add the output from `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Comment: Done. I tried to clear environment and restart R but it didn't help

Comment: It seems that line 5 (PosLimit = last(portf$symbols[[symbol]]$PosLimit[toDate])) in getPosLimit() returns numerical. I have dplyr loaded and it also has last function, so I am pretty sure that's a problem. How in general such problem is solved in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have dplyr loaded. It defines a `lag` function that masks the generic function, `stats::lag`. `dplyr::lag` does not do any method dispatch, so there's a lag method somewhere that isn't being called when it should be.

dplyr also masks the `first` and `last` generics defined in xts, which may also cause problems.

A short-term work-around is to call `library(dplyr)` first, so `first` and `last` in xts will mask their couterparts in dplyr. The long-term solution is that all packages should explicitly import all functions they use to avoid issues caused by the sequence in which packages are loaded/attached (note that user's non-packaged code will still be affected by package load/attach order).

Comment: Short term solution is really bad programming practice :) What if function from other package is only slightly different and do not throw an error and instead just silently slightly change the output? I think long term solution would be much better :)

Comment: @nesvarbu: It's also *really* bad practice to mask generic functions and not do dispatch. As I said in my answer, user's non-packaged code will be affected by package load/attach order because of what dplyr does. I cannot change that. I mentioned the short-term solution so you would have something that works *now*. And I said "short-term" to indicate that it's not ideal. It would be appreciated if you implement the long-term solution and provide a patch. It's simply not a high priority for me.

Comment: Sure np Joshua. Maybe when I have more experience with R I do that

Comment: @nesvarbu: too late. I fixed this over the weekend. ;)

Comment: xaxa that was fast :)